# JavaScript try catch code snippet meaning?

Tags: javascript, try-catch

I'm not able to understand this code snippet in JavaScript. I have seen this in some js library code.

```
var b64pad="";

try 
{ b64pad // Line 3   
 } 
 catch(e) 
 { b64pad=''; }
```

What is happening at line 3 and how JavaScript executes that? 
When I'm converting this js to min.js the convertor complaining with `warning. Suspicious code`

Comment: Very suspicious code. I'm curious, can you show a link? There might be more context we're missing

Comment: It checks if `b64pad` was declared. If it's not declared, a global `b64pad` is created and the empty string is assigned to it. Not an example to follow, though.

Comment: @CertainPerformance it's jsencrypt lib, https://github.com/alfaro28/jsencrypt/tree/master/bin/jsencrypt.js , Line: 1967,1968, Line: 2024, 2042

Comment: @RoboticsLab The provided code doesn't make much sense, but in general, you can write a line of code containing only an expression. That expression is evaluated, but the evaluated value is never used. How ever, if possible side effects of the evaluation are executed. For example `document.body.offsetWidth;` forces the reclaculation of the DOM, eventhough the value is never used anywhere. In your snippet, if `b64pad` wasn't declared, a side effect of evaluating it would be an error throw, which then is catched by `catch`.